# Get-ADUser stored in variable stays connected to DC

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I store information from Active Directory in a variable using this code:

```
$existingstudents = Get-ADUser -Server $DomainContoller -Credential $AdminCredentials -filter 'ObjectClass -eq "user"' -Searchbase $OU
```

any operation on the variable $existingstudents take a long time, especially over a VPN, and it seems like the script is talking back to the domain controller each time. I can see why this would be usefull sometimes, but in my case it just makes the script slow. Is there any way to "dereference" the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really ! I was not knowing about that. The thing you can do is the following :

```
$existingstudents | Export-Clixml -Path c:\temp\t.tmp 
$existingstudents = Import-Clixml -Path c:\temp\t.tmp
```

Lots of stuff to serialize an deserialize an object to keep the data without keeping the behaviour. I think that you should dig your problem a bit more.

Comment: Doing that changed the runtime of the script from about 5 minutes to about 30 seconds, so it at least confirms my theory. I would still like to know if anyone knows a more elegant way to accomplish this.